# why my process always receive signal SIGPIPE, and then pipe broken. I saw it in gdb

Tags: c, linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int pid = fork();
        int one[2];
        int two[2];
        int fp=pipe(one);
        int sp=pipe(two);
        int i;
        char *c1,*c2,a1[8],a2[8];
        c1="doggy";
        c2="wangwang";
        if(fp<0||sp<0)
        perror("pipe failed\n");
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                close(one[1]);
                close(two[0]);
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                        read(one[0],a1,10);
                        printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1,c1);
                        write(two[1],c2,10);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                close(one[0]);
                close(two[1]);
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                        printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1,c2);
                        write(one[1],c1,8);
                        read(two[0],a2,8);
                }


                wait(NULL);
                                                                                          }
}
```

I want to synchronize the parent process and child process by pipe. But in this code, in gdb, I always receive signal SIGPIPE, and then pipe broken. Why?
what is the wrong about the code?

Comment: Q: What's *right* with this code?  Q: Why are you *opening* fp and sp?  Where are "one[]" and "two[]" being initialized?

Comment: try move your fork call after you setup the pipes

Comment: And if the answer below solved your issue it would a nice thing to do to accept it ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the pipes before the fork. fork() will clone the memory, so if you setup the pipes afterwards you dont get one pipe connected with both instances but two not connected pipes. Besides, it is dangerous if you have two pipes and read and write from them. This might deadlock, so be carefull (in your example I think it is ok).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer are correct! I will be careful.